# iOS typography reference or programming guide?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad

I haven't found any documentation from Apple on typography in iOS.
Is there any good book or resource on this topic somewhere you would recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the CoreText framework:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: For kerning and ligatures, you need Core Text

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reference to the available fonts on ios: http://iosfonts.com/

EDIT:

I haven't used this myself but might be helpful: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_text/dq_text.html

Comment: Yes, I've found that too. What I would need is more a library for using typography features like kerning, ligatures, etc.